# Scrapping Table Data from website without class

Tags: python

I want to scrap data from the tables on this [url](https://www.cbe.org.eg/en/Auctions/Pages/AuctionsEGPTBillsHistorical.aspx), but I couldn't find the table class.

I tried the first steps in BeautifulSoup but I couldn't get any further.

```py
from pandas .io.html import read_html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cbe.org.eg/en/Auctions/Pages/AuctionsEGPTBillsHistorical.aspx'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# No class
bills_table = soup.find('table', class_= )
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on that link, a page is displayed containing a date range with the ability to show a table (which I assume is the table you are after) upon a click. You have 2 options here:

1. Simulate the website using a package such as `selenium`
2. Send the post request yourself directly

There is documentation available on `selenium` which should help. I will describe 2 in more detail.

Open the website linked and open the dev panel on whichever browser you are using and navigate to the 'network' tab. Enter a date range and press the show online button as required. A new entry will appear, which is the request we want to make. Click on it and create a new `requests.post(..)` request with the listed request headers and the body. You may want to edit the body to change the date range.